# Interactive Deck came with Easy cards?

Tags: agricola

After owning *Agricola* for quite sometime, I finally got a group of experienced players and decided to use the **I** (*interactive*) deck. I just opened it, and inside the deck there are cards marked with an **E**, which means the card is from the basic (*easy*) deck.

Was that a mistake? Is it on purpose? If so, how the heck am I supposed to figure out which card goes on which deck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The Agricola cards are not wrapped in the box strictly by which deck they belong to.** You'll need to open and sort through all the cards that came with the game. The terms "E-deck", "I-deck", and "K-deck" just refer to subsets of those cards. The E-deck is all of the cards with the E symbol, and so on.

Should you need a manifest of all the cards, [this website](http://alavigne.net/Gaming/Agricola/agricola-comp-v9.0.html) contains a complete list of them. Only the E-, I-, and K-decks are part of the base game; the rest are expansions or promos.

Comment: OMG! I had no idea, why don't they warn us in the box??

Comment: I guess they figure the big "E", "I" or "K" on each card is enough. Also, it's not unheard of to mix the decks - I like I & K together, e.g.